# Beamer framezoom image centered.

Tags: beamer

I'm using framezoom to show details from a big image, I wish the detail, zoomed portion, centered in a frame, how can I do this?.

Thanks,

Comment: How about giving us the code you have so far? Its always a good starting point as one can easily copy and paste, otherwise most people probably won't bother as they have to start from square one or don't even get what your problem really is.

Comment: As the question is vague and the OP did not respond to Tom's comment, I will close the question after it has been open for 2 months. You can edit the question if you like to have it reviewed, we could reopen it then.